# template not rendering with data when using beforeCreated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am not sure why data is not rendering from `this.resp.memo`. I think it should load because it saves the data and then render the veiw and with all the data

```
<template>
  <div class="container" >
      <div class="card mt-3">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5>{{ this.$route.params.id }}</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">

                <b-form-textarea height="100%"
                  id="textarea"
                  auto-grow
                  resize="false"
                  rows="3"
                  class="h-100"
                  v-model="memo_text"
                  :value="`${this.resp.memo}`"  
                  max-rows="">
                </b-form-textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <button class="float-right btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <button class="float-left btn btn-primary" v-on:click="update_memo">Update</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Edit',
  beforeCreate() {
        this.$axios.get('http://172.16.157:5000/api/memo/'+ this.$route.params.id, {  
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }}).then((response) => {
            this.resp = response;
            })
    },
  data() {
    return {
      resp: Object,
    }
  },
    methods: {
        update_memo: function () {
                var obj =  {'id': this.$route.params.id, 'memo': this.memo_text}
                this.$axios.put('http://172.16.157:5000/api/memo', obj, {  
                    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }})
  }
}
}
</script>
<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you verified that you're getting a proper response from the API? And not getting an error?

Comment: yes, I am getting my data back

Comment: instead of using beforeCreate, have you tried mounted() and created()?

Comment: yes, i tried both and more

Comment: Does it show the correct value if you just dump out the value as text using `{{ resp.memo }}` rather than using a `b-form-textarea`?

Comment: I found out there was multiple issues, what i got from server was a bit problematic, and i alter it to function

Answer (score 2):

According to [Vue.js LifeCycle here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), I think it makes sense since `beforeCreate` was called before VueJS initializes the injections and reactivity.

I would recommend moving your get data function into `beforeMount`. You will be allowed to access all Vue Component instances inside `beforeMount`

**UPDATE:**

```
export default {
  name: 'Edit',
  data() {
    return {
      resp: Object,
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
        this.$axios.get('http://172.16.157:5000/api/memo/'+ this.$route.params.id, {  
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }}).then((response) => {
            this.resp = response;
            })
    },
    methods: {
        update_memo: function () {
                var obj =  {'id': this.$route.params.id, 'memo': this.memo_text}
                this.$axios.put('http://172.16.157:5000/api/memo', obj, {  
                    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }})
  }
}
}
```

Or use state management like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) instead